# rails - Unexpected behaviour of 'bundle install': installation into a folder in the app directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bundler

I've started a simple rails application. I tried to install Compass and Haml, (using gem install) and ran 'bundle install'. The bundler re-installed all the gems and placed them in a new folder '/haml' inside the main directory of the rails application.

```
Your bundle is complete! It was installed into ./haml
```

Is that expected? Shouldn't these gems be placed in the rvm directory, not in the application directory?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$ bundle install --system
```

Will solve your problem.

Gems will be installed to your default system location for gems. If your system gems are stored in a root-owned location (such as in Mac OSX), bundle will ask for your root password to install them there.

While installing gems, Bundler will check vendor/cache and then your system's gems. If a gem isn't cached or installed, Bundler will try to install it from the sources you have declared in your Gemfile.

The --system option is the default. Pass it to switch back after using the --path option as described below.

Comment: Thanks that solved the problem. I realized that I mistakenly used 'bundle install haml' which caused the problem.

Comment: I'm sorry! My reputation is not enough yet!